# How do I ensure state change with authentication redirect?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, axios, frontend

My code is a front end with a request from API using axios.
It checks cookie to know if logged in or not for authentication, so if there is no cookie, it redirects to the home page.

```jsx
const PrivateRoute: FunctionComponent<AuthProps> = ({
  component: Component,
  path,
}: AuthProps) => {
  const [isAuth, setisAuth] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/checkcookie', {
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setisAuth(response.data.cookie);
      });
  });
  return (
    <Route
      render={() => {
        return isAuth === true ? <Component /> : <Redirect to="/" />;
      }}
    />
  );
};

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Layout>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Landing} />

            <PrivateRoute path="/inquiries" component={Inquiries} />
            <PrivateRoute
              path="/create-article"
              component={CreateArticle}
            />

            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          </Switch>
        </Layout>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

But the `isAuth` state will change after a request from API, but doesn't change in:

```jsx
 isAuth === true ? <Component /> : <Redirect to="/" />;
```

I just want to make sure that it has the last `isAuth` value.
How do I make sure that it changes state before coming to the condition?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a loading state.

Additional notes:

You will need catch to handle errors.

Add an empty deps array to make sure it runs only once.

```
const PrivateRoute: FunctionComponent<AuthProps> = ({
  component: Component,
  path,
}: AuthProps) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isAuth, setisAuth] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/checkcookie', {
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setisAuth(response.data.cookie);
      })
      .catch(console.log)
      .finally(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <></>;
  }

  return (
    <Route
      render={() => {
        return isAuth === true ? <Component /> : <Redirect to="/" />;
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `response.data.cookie` a boolean value? If, for example, `response.data.cookie = '32094jwef9u23sdkf'` then `isAuth === true` will *never* evaluate `true` and redirect will always render. Also, it is common, and more correct, to never test directly against `true` or `false`, just use the javascript truthy/falsey-ness of variable values.

Check the react-router-dom [auth-workflow](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow) example.

The thing to notice here is that the auth check is ***in*** the `render` prop. The reason for this is the private route will only be rendered once when the `Router` is rendered, but the matched routed will render/rerender its children when necessary.

1. Try moving the auth check into the `render` prop.
2. Add a loading state and return null while the auth check is pending, use `.finally` block to signal not loading.
3. Save a boolean `isAuth` value if cookie exists or not.

Code:

```
const PrivateRoute: FunctionComponent<AuthProps> = ({
  component: Component,
  path,
}: AuthProps) => {
  return (
    <Route
      render={(routeProps) => {
        const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

        useEffect(() => {
          setLoading(true);
          axios
            .get('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/checkcookie', {
              withCredentials: true,
            })
            .then((response) => {
              setIsAuth(!!response.data.cookie);
            })
            .finally(() => setLoading(false));
        }, []);

        if (loading) return null;

        return isAuth ? <Component {...routeProps} /> : <Redirect to="/" />;
      }}
    />
  );
};
```